# Dynamic dropdown in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

Im making a website for school and I needed a dynamic dropdown. I went about making it using this tutorial [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tD9hb9zIvBQ).

I have finished the first 6 parts and everything worked. In the last part when the first dropdown should appear it just doesn't. If the question is hard to answer or could have more answers just tell me what comes to mind and ill check. 
Ty in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>askldfjdasklf</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name "viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>

    <label>Starost</label>
    <select id="starost"></select><br>
    <label>Praznuje</label>
    <select id="praznuje"></select><br>

    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
<pre>$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $.getJSON("get_starost.php", success = function(data)
    {
        var options = "";

        for (var i 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            options += "<option value='" + data[i].toLowerCase() + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
        }
        $("#starost").append(options);

    }); 
});
</pre>

<pre>
<?php 
    require "opendb.php";

    $query = "SELECT starost FROM filter_starost";
    $data = mysql_query($query, $conn);

    $starost = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data))
    {
        array_push($starost, $row["starost"]);
    }
    echo json_encode($starost);

    require "closedb.php";
?>
</pre>
```

Comment: You're missing equals signs.

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle? go to jsfiddle.net, write your code and paste a link here.

Comment: And `$.getJSON("get_starost.php", success = function(data)` isn't valid syntax, you need to use an object literal in the arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  are missing `=` `i 0`in you for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{ 

}
```

and open web browser console to check errors and for debug. This will help you a  lot.

Comment: thank you, yes I was missing the equals. (the night was long and its almost noon :))

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $.getJSON("get_starost.php", function(data)
    {
        var options = "";

        for (var i= 0; i " + data[i] + "";
        }
        $("#starost").append(options);

    }); 
});
```

Replace `<pre>` with `<script>`
also remove `success =`